# Can't get MTR to use an IP

Tags: 14.04, networking, windows-10

I am running the linux subsystem through windows with the new update.

When I type in mtr [ip] as I usually would, it starts as I if I didn't type in an IP at all. Pressing **y** when in mtr doesn't do anything. I've tried starting as sudo without any luck.

Standard apps such as ping, and traceroute work without any problems. As far as I know mtr is the only one having this issue right now.

[mtr not working.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYm4j.gif)

Comment: I think youi're confusing what that IP is.  I'll give more details in an answer shortly.

Comment: I don't have WSL here, but please read my response.  It explains the IP address you're seeing a bit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a screenshot of `mtr 8.8.8.8` from my own actual Ubuntu computer in the Terminal:

[image]

As you can see, it also shows my IP address on my system as `0.0.0.0`.  However, that's only an indicator of what IP address `mtr` is binding to for outgoing packets.

In computing theory, 0.0.0.0 means "Any IP address, or the Default Route".  If your computer only has one IP address, the default route that `0.0.0.0` refers to is the IP address and router your system is connected to.  The IP address therefore you're referencing has nothing to do with what you're seeing.

Now, if `mtr` on WSL doesn't properly show pings/packets, that's an issue between WSL and `mtr` and could indicate an oddity within WSL that you should probably take up with either `mtr` upstream or the WSL bug trackers.